Is there a way to find/restore files from temporary printing folder?
I have opened my visa application page with Print Preview and thought that it was saved this way. But now, I can't find it anywhere on my mac, and there is not way to review it on the website either.
This is a path where files are put when I open them in Print Preview, but all the previous "printing" folders are empty.
I really need this application :(



Is there a printing.25918.9 folder in the list shown in the second screenshot?

yes, there is. but it's folder with only the files i opened today

and on the first screenshot - it's the today's file, not the one I'm looking for

When did you open the file you are missing now? How did you receive it, via Mail or via download from a web page?

I opened it 6 days ago (may 27). I pressed the "print" button on the web page, and opened it in preview (and I thought it saved this way)
